# How to show an object value in for loop in java script

Tags: javascript, node.js, for-loop

I need to print all datas in an object in a for loop but I don't know how to access to their index.

For example I have an object like this (this is an example ,but the real one is very big)

```
a = { name : richard ,last_name : stallman };
```

I can do this :

```
cnosole.log(a.name);
cnosole.log(a.last_name);
```

But the object is too big.How can I do this?

Comment: Try `console.dir(a)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Our you could do it like this:

```
a = { name : 'richard' ,last_name : 'stallman' };

for( key in a){
    console.log(a[key]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert an object to a string with `JSON.stringify`.

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(a));
```

should print something like:

```
{"name": "richard", "last_name": "stallman"}
```

Comment: Are you sure this answers the question?

Comment: I don't need to print them like this ,I need to make changes and print this data in them.